# Process cannot be killed on linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I wrote the following (rather stupid) C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>



void myHandler(int signum) {

    printf("This will never be printed...\n");

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sigaction s1;
    s1.sa_handler=myHandler;

    sigset_t sigs;
    sigfillset(&sigs);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigs, NULL);

    sigaction(SIGINT, &s1, NULL);

    while (1) sleep();

    return 1;

}
```

Now it cannot be killed from terminal!
When I try executing '*kill 4242*' from terminal (4242 is the process id), it ignores it!
Of course, my intention was that this process will ignore all signals, but SIGKILL **cannot** be ignored, can it?
How can I kill this process?

BTW, when running '*ps*' from terminal it will **not** show it on the list:

```
 4348 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
 4444 pts/8    00:00:00 ps
```

it will only show it when I run '*ps -u my_username*' (along with a bunch others). Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: What if you try `ps -ef`? It must appear there. And then just `kill id` or even `kill -9 id`.

Comment: Plain `kill` sends SIGTERM, not SIGKILL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the `kill` command sends `SIGTERM`. If you want to kill your program with `SIGKILL`, use `kill -KILL 4242`.

Another thing I find handy if a process ignores `^C`, just press `^Z`, it will suspend the process and give you back the control of the terminal, then you can kill the process with `kill %`.

Comment: The way this program was written, it also ignored `Ctrl-Z`...
`kill -KILL 4242` did the trick... :)